# Downloading a web page through proxy

Tags: perl, proxy

I am trying to download a webpage through a proxy connection with the following code:

```
use LWP::Simple qw(get);
my $url = 'https://www.random-site.com';
my $html = get $url or die "sorry, can't";
```

I get the obvious error `sorry, can't`.

The code works on a normal connection,but on proxy it doesn't and even with the `Hideman` program, it still doesn't bypass that proxy. Which would be a better approach in this situation? Am I using the wrong module?

Answer (score 0):

Note [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple):

> The user agent created by this module will identify itself as "LWP::Simple/#.##" and will initialize its proxy defaults from the environment (by calling $ua->env_proxy).

Then, note [`env_proxy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-env_proxy):

> Load proxy settings from *_proxy environment variables.

So, set `HTTPS_PROXY` in the environment.

Comment: http_proxy env will not affect https requests; https_proxy is needed instead.

Comment: Since an unexperienced user in the proxy domain comes andd asks a question, it's not helpfull to point him the user manual of something.
A "hello world" example would have been more helpfull.
I did not understood half of the terms from there

Comment: I managed to follow your instructions, yet they didn't work. I used the example from the duplicate link.

Comment: @TedyGrey I assume basic familiarity with your operating environment and tools.

Comment: @Tedy Grey, refer to the https connect examples from http://search.cpan.org/~benning/LWP-Protocol-connect-6.05/lib/LWP/Protocol/connect.pm. This assumes your proxy supports https connect passthrough. You need to ensure you have the module installed.